# Dispose Player WMPLib

Tags: c#, .net, wmplib

I have multiple initialized WMPLib players in my code. I want to be able to kill some of them on command. I know how to make an event, but not how to dispose those Players since I just don't want them to exist anymore.

There's

```cs
Player.controls.stop();
```

but  is this seriously the way to do it? How can I dispose it on command (i.e event trigger)?

Comment: WMP is a COM server, it therefore does not have a Dispose() method.  Use GC.Collect() if necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant I just want to destroy it; i.e kill it forever